# Responsive Web Design - Disappearing style?

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I am new to responsive design and searched around but it seems too broad a topic to find the right solution.

I spent hours last night getting my Nav good for computer/tablet/smart phones. It all looked great. Tested in on a number of computers and devices. Today I went to work on it and when the browser window is extended beyond 1200px the header and footer mess up. Using Firebug it looks like the Divs are there but 1px high, no content in them. I don't know what changed in the time I was at work away from my computer but it's driving me insane.

http://www.wallyhawk.com/responsive/

Really appreciate any help. I'm about 5 hours on this one issue and out of ideas.

Comment: Post the `@media (min-width: 1200px)` or alike CSS.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. Copy the styles onto here?

Comment: Yeah, but only the ones regarding `>1200px`. They are enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in your Main.css remove `color:#fff` from this element
 `.mainmenu > ul > li > a, .mainmenu .mainmenu-submenu-inner > li > a`.

You should see all the menu.

Comment: Appreciate the effort but the text there is supposed to be white. There is supposed to be a green background fed by an image. Shrink the browser window down and it works on smaller sizes, its just the big size that decided to break.